# GetProcessImageFileName and LPTSTR

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Someone can say if I'm using it right ?

```
LPTSTR nameProc = "";
...
GetProcessImageFileName( hProcess, nameProc, 50 );

printf("name process : %s\n", nameProc);
```

I'm not used with the win32 types,
the 2nd argument of the **GetProcessImageFileName** requires a **LPTSTR** typedef and the third one takes a **DWORD** variable.
if not the method maybe i'm not printing the value of **nameProc** the right way ? (it prints an empty string by the way)

thanks in advance.

(please try to avoid leading me to some win32 api documents, i have no intention to learn about it, i just need to trace the usage memory of one process, therefore I won't no longer deal with win types)

EDIT (updated code):

```
void printMemoryInfo( DWORD processID ) {

    HANDLE hProcess;
    TCHAR nameProc[MAX_PATH];

    printf("\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID);

    hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID );

    if (hProcess == NULL) return;

    if (GetProcessImageFileName( hProcess, nameProc, sizeof(nameProc)/sizeof(*nameProc) )==0)
        printf("error\n");

    else printf("%s\n", nameProc);
}

int main (void) {

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if (!EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded )) {

        return 1;
    }

    cProcesses = cbNeeded/sizeof(DWORD);

    for (i=0; i < cProcesses; i++) {

    printMemoryInfo( aProcesses[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nameProc` needs to be a mutable buffer as it is an output parameter, at the moment it will probably just crash. Change this:

```
LPTSTR nameProc = "";
```

to this:

```
TCHAR nameProc[MAX_PATH];
```

Also pass `MAX_PATH` where you are passing 50 at the moment.

Comment: thanks, it works for some process Identifiers.
it doesn't seem to want printing the filename of the process in which I execute this program (but in fact the processId is in the list initialized with enumProcesses). any idea why ?

Comment: Can you update your post to include the code which enumerates the processes.

Comment: @Oddant Try changing `TCHAR nameProc[50];` to `TCHAR nameProc[MAX_PATH];`. Your buffer is far too small.

Answer (score 4):

You may not want to learn about the Win32 types (and IMHO it's quite a bad idea, since programming on Windows often the APIs come useful), but even without understanding what a `LPTSTR` is the MSDN documentation is quite explicit about the second parameter:

> *lpImageFileName* [out]
>
> A pointer to a buffer that receives the full path to the executable file.

So it's quite clear that your `nameProc` isn't OK, since you aren't allocating any memory for it. You'll probably want to write:

```
TCHAR nameProc[MAX_PATH];
if(GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, nameProc, sizeof(nameProc)/sizeof(*nameProc))==0)
{
    // some error happened
}
```